# Why is $2^{\aleph_0}>\aleph_0$, but ${\aleph_0}^2=\aleph_0$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, intuition, cardinals, infinity

I understand the direct arguments as to why $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$. What I'm wondering about is if there is some straightforward/intuitive explanation as to why "infinity being in the exponent" is the magic line that bumps things up to the next cardinality, while $\aleph_0+\aleph_0=\aleph_0$ and $\aleph_0 \cdot \aleph_0=\aleph_0$, $(\aleph_0)^x=\aleph_0$, etc., or whether this is just a result that comes from the math that needs to be accepted.

Comment: $2^{\aleph_0}$ is strictly greater than $\aleph_0$, but it is not necessarily equal to $\aleph_1.$ This is the continuum hypothesis.

Comment: Also $\aleph_0^x$ is not equal to $\aleph_0$ unless $x$ is finite. In fact, ${\aleph_0}^{\kappa}=2^{\kappa}$ for any $\kappa\ge \aleph_0$.

Comment: Why do you think they should be the same? Why is $2^{100}$ so much bigger than $100^2$?

Comment: Yep, I'm assuming CH, I figured that was implied.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think, a possible *not-so-good* explanation may be that any infinity taken once or twice or any **finite** number of times doesn't change anything. We can extend our idea of constructing bijections from $\mathbb A\to \mathbb A\times \mathbb A$ to constructing bijections from $\mathbb A\to \mathbb A\times \mathbb A\times \dots \times \mathbb A$ where there are only finite number of $\mathbb A$'s in there.

But, when you take an infinity infinite number of times, that's when *we add another dimension of infinity*. It's intuitively similar to why there is no bijection from $\mathbb A \to \mathbb A\times \mathbb A\times \mathbb A\times\dots$ where there are infinite number of $\mathbb A$'s (this can be easily proved using Cantor's diagonalisation argument if $\mathbb A=\mathbb N$).

Rob Arthan pointed out that the second paragraph doesn't make sense for larger infinities than $\mathbb N$. While that's true, what I actually meant was this adding *another dimension of infinity* part. Since $\mathbb N$ is a smaller infinity than $\mathbb R$, taking $\mathbb R$, $\mathbb N$ times still doesn't change much. But when you take $\mathbb R$, $\mathbb R$ times, that's when the infinity changes.

And, about Trevor's question of $2^{\aleph_0}$,  I would rather think of $2^{\mathbb A}$ as the collection of **all** subsets of $\mathbb A$. Now, if you take only the collection of one-element subsets of $\mathbb A$, that's the same infinity as that of $\mathbb A$. Same holds for a collection of $k$ element subsets of $\mathbb A$ where $k$ is finite or a strictly smaller infinity than that of $\mathbb A$. But, when you take **all** the subsets, that's when you are *adding that dimension*.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Your second paragraph is not correct: $\Bbb{R}$ is equipollent with $\Bbb{R}^\Bbb{N}$, i.e., $\Bbb{R} \times \Bbb{R} \times \Bbb{R}\times \ldots$ with a countably infinite number of $\Bbb{R}$s.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the sort of answer I was looking for; in order to reach a higher cardinality, an infinity must be applied to itself, and you don't find that in the lesser expressions I gave.

Comment: Actually, wait -- it's a good explanation as to why ${\aleph_0}^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$, but what about $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$? That's still just "doing something with something finite" (multiplying 2s) infinity times, just as $2\aleph_0$ is adding 2s infinity times, but clearly with different results between the two.

Comment: @RobArthan Oh yes! What I meant was this *adding another dimension of infinity* part. Since $\mathbb N$ is a smaller infinity than $\mathbb R$, taking $\mathbb R$, $\mathbb N$ times still doesn't change much. But when you take $\mathbb R$, $\mathbb R$ times, that's when the infinity changes.

Comment: @Trevor Yes, but I think of it in a different way. I would rather think of $2^{\mathbb A}$ as the collection of **all** subsets of $\mathbb A$. Now, if you take only the collection of one-element subsets of $\mathbb A$, that's the same infinity as that of $\mathbb A$. Same holds for a collection of $k$ element subsets of $\mathbb A$ where $k$ is finite or a strictly smaller infinity than that of $\mathbb A$. But, when you take **all** the subsets, that's when you are *adding that dimension*.

Comment: Actually, I had this same question when I was studying infinities. And, this is the explanation that I gave to myself. And this never failed to provide me with the correct intuitive guess. I would really love to have some pathetic or marginal case where this approach no longer works.

Comment: @Kyky Yes, I know this proof, and that's what I said. Since $2^\mathbb A$ is the collection of **all** subsets of $\mathbb A$, we must have this one added *dimension of infinity* which makes it a greater infinity than $\mathbb A$.

Answer (score 1):

I had a thought; this is coming from a compsci perspective and offers another way to view the $2^x$ aspect of it.

Suppose you have magic RAM that can do the things I'm about to describe.

You store some data of length $\aleph_0$ on it. To reference specific individual elements (or bits) of your data, you can do it by providing an address, and that address will always be some finite sequence of bits, a binary number. Since the union of all possible addresses (all finite numbers) will suffice to let you access the entire object, and since all finite numbers jointly comprise $\mathbb N$, mapping to $\aleph_0$, this checks out as the size of the data.

You also store some data of length $\aleph_1$ on it. To reference specific bits of *this* object, each address will need to be a bit string of length $\aleph_0$. Since this much addressing information is sufficient to map an address to every bit in the object, it's also a measure of the size of the object itself, as we know that $2^{\aleph_0}$ describes every possible address for such an object, and therefore corresponds to its size. This is similar to how $32$ bits is exactly what you need to describe the location of a specific byte within $4$ GB, which is $2^{32}$ bytes.

Answer (score 0):

We avoid using the OP's cardinality statements, casting them instead in terms of the objects $\Bbb N$ and $2^{\Bbb N}$.

We can also equivalently use the power set $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb N)$ to represent $2^{\Bbb N}$.

If you are presented with the (impossible) task of constructing a surjective mapping from $\Bbb N$ to $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb N)$ begin by contemplating the injective mapping

$\quad \kappa: \; n \mapsto \{n\}$

The function $\kappa$ is only hitting the singletons and has the following properties

$\quad \forall n \; n \in \kappa(n)$

$\quad \emptyset \notin \kappa(\Bbb N)$

If we could change $\kappa$ so that for some integer $b$, $\,\kappa(b) = \emptyset$, then $b \notin \kappa(b)$.

We now intuitively realize that if $\kappa$ were to become a surjection the set

$\tag 1 B = \{b \in \Bbb N \mid b \notin \kappa(b)\}$

would be of interest - $\kappa$ must *disassociate* from the initial integer *atoms* to get full coverage.

The set $B$ is a *measure* (in the imagination) of how much $\kappa$ is a *disassociative* mapping. And it would certainly be amusing if there was no way that $B$ itself could be in the range of $\kappa$.

But that is indeed the case; see the [proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem#Proof) of Cantor's theroem.